# WebGL: How can you draw a pentagon?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I am practicing WebGL and attempting to draw a pentagon, but I am not sure how to approach this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What are you drawing now? Have you drawn a triangle? A rectangle? [Show some code please](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: This question it too broad. There are infinite ways to draw a pentagon in WebGL and without more details and some code there' s no way to know what you're asking. If you're asking for someone to teach you webgl then that's a very large topic and you should go [read some tutorials](https://webfundamentals.org). For now voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to do this with `three.js`. You can use `CircleGeometry` and reduce the number of segments to five to give you a pentagon.

```
var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 10, 5 )
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } )
var circle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
scene.add( circle )
```

More information here: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CircleGeometry

Within a working example:

```js
var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setClearColor(0x8e8ed7)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

var scene = new THREE.Scene()
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 0.1, 3000)
camera.position.set(0, 0, 100)
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.minDistance = 40
controls.maxDistance = 1300
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF0000, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75})

scene.add(camera, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4))
var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.8)

camera.add(light)
light.position.y += 60
light.position.x += 70

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})

var geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( 10, 5 )
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } )
var circle = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material )
scene.add( circle )
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: this is not an answer to how to draw a pentagon in webgl, it's an answer on how to draw a pentagon in three.js. three.js is not webgl. By analogy if someone asked "how do I draw a pentagon in C++" and you answered with a JavaScript example using canvas2d because both JavaScript and Canvas2D are written in C++

Comment: the question itself is off topic for stack overflow. answering off topic question is considered bad as it just encourages more off topic questions. I did the responsible thing and voted to close it. If the questioner fixes the question so it's on topic I'll remove my close vote and leave an answer

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use only webgl, first of all you need to create vertices, for this you can use a circle, select five points on a circle at equal distances from each other and lying on a circle, here is the formula for each coordinate

```
let vertices =[];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++){
  let x = radius * Math.cos(360/5 * i);
  let y = radius * Math.sin(360/5 * i);
  vertices.push(x);vertices.push(y);
}
```

substituting your required radius instead of the radius, you will get a set of coordinates of your pentagon, and then drop them into the buffer of your program and draw, tried to show as briefly as possible

Comment: i can draw it for you,  if you want